# show T is one one iff $\ker(T)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove $T:V\rightarrow W$ is linear transformation implies $T(au+bv)=aTu+bTv$ and vice versa. also show $T$ is one-one iff $\ker(T)=0$

My attempt:

This by definition of linear transformation should be should be so, and second can be shown by counter that if $\ker(T)$ is not $0$ then two vectors in V are mapped to $0 in $W.$ so it cannot be 1-1. is it right?

Comment: Yes, but you're not done. You also need to show that if there are two different vectors $u\neq v$ such that $T(u)=T(v)$, then the kernel is non-zero. Said differently, you've shown (by contrapositivity) that injectivity implies zero kernel, you still need to show that zero kernel implies injectivity.

Comment: What definition were you given for linearity? It seems like an  odd problem to ask if that is the definition.

Comment: You've been a member of this website for seven months, by now you should be able to typeset mathematics here... [See this for a tutorial.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: if T is linear then  T(au+bv)=aTu+bTv is by definition. no book proves it. but the question here needs proof.

Comment: @BigBang That is not how all books define it. Some define it as $T(u+v)=Tu+Tv$ and $T(av)=aTv$. Don't state absolutes about non-mathematics, it makes you look foolish.

Comment: All you/ve shows is that if $\ker T\neq\{0\}$ then $T$ is not $1-1$. Now you need to show that if $\ker T=\{0\}$ then $T$ is $1-1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews its one and same thing.

Comment: Literally, it is not the same thing, until you prove it is the same thing. Duh.  Beginning undergrad courses often have such "basic" proofs as problems, and they are highly important to  gaining mathematical knowledge. Don't be obtuse. If your course defind it my way, and asked you to prove this, would you say "by definition" is a correct answer? Of course not. @BigBang

Comment: In particular, if $R$ is a commutative ring without identity, and you defined $R$-module, then your definition of transform of $R$-modules would not be the same as my definition - you can't prove $T(a+b)=T(a)+T(b)$ from your definition. So you need that additional property of $\mathbb R$ - having an identity - to make them equivalent. Hence: Requires proof. @BigBang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a  formal proof of the first part you can start from the usual [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) of a linear transformation that see that $T$ is linear if $\forall \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v} \in V$ and $\forall a \in K$ we have:
$$
T(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})=T(\mathbf{u})+T(\mathbf{v}) \quad and \quad aT(\mathbf{v})=T(a \mathbf{v})
$$
From these we have:
$$
T(a\mathbf{u}+b\mathbf{v})=T(a\mathbf{u})+T(b\mathbf{v})=aT(\mathbf{u})+bT(\mathbf{v})
$$
and using  $a=b=1$ or $b=0$ you prove the inverse statement, as suggested in teh comment of Thomas Andrews.

For the second claim consider the answer of Omnomnomnom.

Comment: Except you also have to prove $T(au+bv)=aT(u)+bT(v)$ implies linearity, so you've only proven the first half of the first problem. The second half actually requires some knowledge about vector spaces - specifically, that $1,0$ are scalars and $1v=v$ and $0v=0$ and $v+0=v$. The first direction is true for any definition of $(u,v)\mapsto u+v$ and $(a,u)\mapsto au$.

Comment: @Thomas: Good point.! I add to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "by definition of linearity" is not enough for the first part. If we have $x\neq y$ such that $T(x)=T(y)$, then how do we know that there is a non-zero element in the kernel of $T$?

**Hint:** Consider $x-y$.